# Prove $F$ is real analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $F:C \rightarrow R$ is a $C2$ smooth function satisfying

$\frac{\partial F}{{\partial x}{\partial y}}$  = $3(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}$ + $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} )$

How can we prove it's real analytic?

My attempt is to prove $F$ is holomorphic by $CR$ equation, then $F$ is real analytic just follows. But I'm having problems using the laplacian condition.

Follow from the hint by Mr.eyeballfrog:

So we would have $F(x,y) = F(\zeta(x,y), \eta(x,y))$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ = $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x}$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}$ = $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$a$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$c$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ = $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial y}$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}$ = $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$b$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$d$

Then $(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}$ + $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} )$ = $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$($\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$a$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$c$) + $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$($\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$b$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$d$)

and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ = $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$($\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}$$b$ + $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$$d$)

Comment: If the equation were just $\nabla^2 F = 0$, could you solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah, then we can prove F is harmonic which is also real analytic.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Make a linear change of variables $\xi = ax + by;\; \eta = cx + dy$ such that the differential operator is $\partial_{\xi}^2 + \partial_{\eta}^2$.

Comment: Are we trying to write $(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}$ + $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} )$ as $(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \zeta^2}$ + $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \eta^2} )$ or did I just misunderstand your hint?